# How to install coreboot/libreboot on Thinkpad x220

Tags: linux, bios, thinkpad

I am interested to replace my BIOS on my Thinkpad x220, because I want to remove the white list for other wifi cards.
At first I was thinking to use a modificated BIOS from one of these russian boards, but I don't trust them.

I found out, that it's possible to use coreboot/libreboot. I'm a little bit scared to do it, because I don't have tools to recover the original BOIS on the chip.

So what's the best way to install coreboot/libreboot on my x220?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [coreboot documentation for the x220](https://www.coreboot.org/Board:lenovo/x220), you need to open the x220 use an external SPI flasher to install coreboot.

> Proceeds as follows:
>
> Turn off your laptop, remove battery and AC adapter.
>   Remove the keyboard. 
>   Lift the left side of the plating (see pictures above)
>   Connect your external SPI flasher to the top SPI chip (pictured). It's
>   a 8M chip. The chip is layout is as so:

...

> Read the flash. Twice. Compare the files to be sure. Save a copy of it on external media.

So it seems you can't install `coreboot` without the tools needed to restore your BIOS.

> So what's the best way to install coreboot/libreboot on my x220?

You'll have to buy (or borrow) the necessary SPI flasher.